# Can't retrieve data using dynamic SQL from the function that returns the table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, dynamic

My types:

```
TYPE T_rowBalanceListForClient IS RECORD
(
    RowCode Asset.RowCode%TYPE,
    RowName Asset.RowName%TYPE
);  
TYPE T_tableBalanceListForClient IS TABLE OF T_rowBalanceListForClient;
```

My function:

```
FUNCTION F_BalanceListForClient
(
    p_ClientId Client.ClientId%TYPE
)
RETURN T_tableBalanceListForClient PIPELINED
AS
    CURSOR CUR_TABLE IS
        SELECT
                RowCode,
                RowName
            FROM Asset;
BEGIN

    FOR CUR_REC IN CUR_TABLE LOOP
        PIPE ROW(CUR_REC);
    END LOOP;

END;
```

Part of my stored procedure:

```
    sql_statement := ' SELECT * FROM TABLE(:1)';
    OPEN c_Result FOR sql_statement USING F_BalanceListForClient(11);
```

While building the package I reseive the Oracle error:

PLS-00457: expressions have to be of SQL types

In the common stored procedures calls like this are built and operate well (not dynamics):

```
PROCEDURE GET_BALANCE_STANDARD_LIST
(
    c_Result OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    p_ClientId Client.ClientId%TYPE DEFAULT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN c_Result FOR
        SELECT RowName FROM TABLE(F_BalanceListForClient(p_ClientId));
END;
```

Appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: did you try doing `TABLE(F_BalanceListForClient(:1))`?

Comment: Yes, it was my first attempt. The error was 'Improper identificator' or simething like this. I've googled all the day and found the solution like I've described in my question, but it also returns the error.

Comment: Is `F_BalanceListForClient` of type `T_tableBalanceListForClient`?

Comment: Yes Jafar, you can see it in the function body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_rowBalanceListForClient IS OBJECT 
(
    RowCode NUMBER,
    RowName VARCHAR2(200)
);  


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_tableBalanceListForClient AS TABLE OF T_rowBalanceListForClient;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_BalanceListForClient
(
    p_ClientId NUMBER        
)
RETURN T_tableBalanceListForClient PIPELINED
AS
CURSOR CUR_TABLE IS
        SELECT
                RowCode,
                RowName
            FROM Assets
          ;    --put a filter of the p_clientId


BEGIN

    FOR CUR_REC IN CUR_TABLE
    LOOP

       pipe row (T_rowBalanceListForClient (CUR_REC.RowCode, CUR_REC.RowName));

    END LOOP;

RETURN;

END;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_BALANCE_STANDARD_LIST
(
    c_Result OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    p_ClientId NUMBER DEFAULT NULL
)
AS
sql_statement varchar2(200);

BEGIN

 sql_statement := ' SELECT * FROM TABLE(F_BalanceListForClient(:1))';
    OPEN c_Result FOR sql_statement USING p_ClientId;

END;
/

BEGIN

GET_BALANCE_STANDARD_LIST(:cur ,11);

END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you Gaurav, for your solution, but I've decided to use 'View' instead of function. It looks much more neat and works properly. Unfortunately I can't increase your rating - I lack my one for it, but once I have more than 15 - I'll do it.

Comment: @xborus:Its not about rating ,just try to understand how this can be achieved ,that is more important for us .FYI ,increasing rating does not reduce your rating as well as accepting the answer .Infact if you accept the answer you'll get 2 reputation .But no issues ,my intention here is to make you aware of this ,Share and enjoy:)